# how to hide child element of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to remove "Hello this is short description 1 " (plz see code) line dynamically , on accordian button ("section-1", "section-2", "section-3") click. right now it's being remove but the only problem is that it's removing all other button text, I want it should be remove only from that buttton where I have clicked. this is my code.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;
        var short = document.getElementsByClassName('short-desc')
        
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            
           
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                
                
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                
                
                if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                    panel.style.display = "none";
                    
                }
    
                else {
                    panel.style.display = "block";
                    $(".short").closest('small').hide();
                    
                }
            });
        }
```

```css
.accordion {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #444;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    .active, .accordion:hover {
      background-color: #ccc; 
    }
    
    .panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      display: none;
      background-color: white;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Accordion</h2>
    
    <button class="accordion">Section 1
     
        <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 1 </small>
    
    </button>
    <div class="panel">
       
      <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    
    <button class="accordion">Section 2
        <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 2 </small>
        <p id="short-desc2" style="display:none;">Hello this is short description </p>
    </button>
    <div class="panel">
       
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    
    <button class="accordion">Section 3
        <small class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 3</small>
    </button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: do you mean by removing, collapsing accordion elements?

Comment: I have checked your code in fiddle, It's hide and show the div. and it's working fine. So what is your query?

Comment: @VivekRaju as in the question - it removes the text from all sections, OP wants it only removed from clicked-on section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var short = document.getElementsByClassName('short-desc')

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {

    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
            $(this).children("small.short").show();
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
            $(this).children("small.short").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1

    <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 1 </small>

</button>
<div class="panel">

  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2
    <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 2 </small>
    <p id="short-desc2" style="display:none;">Hello this is short description </p>
</button>
<div class="panel">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3
    <small class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 3</small>
</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just small issue in your code. change your line to `$(this).find('small').hide();`

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    var short = document.getElementsByClassName('short-desc')

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {


        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {


            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;


            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";

            }

            else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
                $(this).find('small').hide();

            }
        });
    }
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1

    <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 1 </small>

</button>
<div class="panel">

  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2
    <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 2 </small>
    <p id="short-desc2" style="display:none;">Hello this is short description </p>
</button>
<div class="panel">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3
    <small class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 3</small>
</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)`

```js
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    var short = document.getElementsByClassName('short-desc')

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {

       
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
          
            var _t = $(this);

            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;


            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";

            }

            else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
                 _t.find(".short").closest('small').hide();

            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1

    <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 1 </small>

</button>
<div class="panel">

  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2
    <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 2 </small>
    <p id="short-desc2" style="display:none;">Hello this is short description </p>
</button>
<div class="panel">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3
    <small class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 3</small>
</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change from

```
$(".short").closest('small').hide();
```

to

```
this.querySelector('small').style.display = 'none';
```

```js
   var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    var short = document.getElementsByClassName('short-desc')

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {


        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {


            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;


            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";

            }

            else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
                //console.log(this.querySelector('small'))
                this.querySelector('small').style.display = 'none';

            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1

    <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 1 </small>

</button>
<div class="panel">

  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2
    <small  class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 2 </small>
    <p id="short-desc2" style="display:none;">Hello this is short description </p>
</button>
<div class="panel">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3
    <small class="short" style="color:red; display:block">Hello this is short description 3</small>
</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```